# Problem connecting pi b+3 model with ethernet cable on a windows machine

Tags: ethernet

I've read multiple guides on how to connect a raspberry pi with a pc through internet yet I always fail . I have a windows machine,I did share the wifi connection with the ethernet which the pi is connected to. I also did activate ssh from the sudo raspi-config menu beforehand (but did not add an ssh file) on the pi. I also read the pi's ip using the advanced ip scanner program yet I cannot connect on the pi. Both Putty and VNC viewer say "network refused" whenever I try to connect. And yes I did consider restarting the machine multiple times to ensure sharing is applied.
I tried the exact same steps on another machine on another network and got the same problem. Can anyone give me a hint? I'm getting kinda desperate.Thanks for your time. I'll post an answer if I find one.

Comment: disconnect the RPi and try again .... do you still get  "network refused" ?

Comment: Just to clarify.... The Pi is connected to a Windows PC... The Windows PC is connected to the Internet... and the Pi is connected to the Windows PC ethernet port and is receiving an IP address lease from a DHCP server in a wifi router through the Windows PC bridged wifi and ethernet... Is that correct?  ... And you are attempting to connect to the Pi from the Windows PC?

Comment: Pi is connected with ethernet on the pc and the pc is connected via wifi on the router and has internet access. The only thing I did was to share the wifi network with the ethernet. I'm sorry but I don't know what a DHCP server is . The sharing between the ethernet network and the wifi network is not bridged.

Comment: OK... so... what is the IP address of the Pi ? and what is the IP address of the Windows PC?

Comment: The IP address of the window machine is known but I can't see the IP address of the pi if it isn't connected to my router. The ethernet network doesn't show an IP or I don't know how to see it when i connect it with the pi.I think there was a command line using cmd,ping and arp -a  ?

Comment: After looking through some of the Windows ICS documentation... As @Milliways indicates it's either not possible or rather difficult to configure clients to be able to fully communicate with the ICS host in Windows...  this is not an RPi related problem.  It's fully a Windows related problem.

Comment: @RubberStamp what is the problem with ICS? ICS provides a DHCP- and DNS-server so `dhcpcd` on the RasPi should get an ip address from the Windows PC and everything is good. What do I missing?

Comment: @Ingo ... I haven't used Windows in years... so, this is a surprise to me too... but it looks like there is no method to configure routing between the ICS host back to the clients... but `arp /a` looks like it should show that on the Windows ICS host according to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/arp) ... Perhaps I'm wrong --- In either case, this question is not a RPi question, it's a MS Windows question.

Answer (score 1):

You can have **either** ICS or `ssh` access **NOT** both!

Connect the Pi to your router.

Comment: I'm not a windows user so I do not understand why a host connected to a windows pc that provides [Internet Connection Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) cannot be reached by `ssh` (putty?). Even the *Limitations* section on the link to Wikipedia does not give any hints. Can you please explain?

Comment: @Ingo I am not a Windows user either - this is not just a Windows issue it also applies to macOS. (I know it is possible to setup bridging in other ways but simple layer 2 bridging seems to be the only offering.) Similar questions have been asked on this site dozens of times. Routers are so cheap and readily available it hardly seems worth trying to decipher the arcane Windows  stack.